# Showing Tweets of a User in his account on mywebsite once he has allowed my website to his twitter account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my webapp I want to show the recent tweets of a logged-in user.

I've connected user's twitter account to my application using Omniauth and have stored the auth token and secret in the database for the future use.

So I want, as a user logged in to mywebapp, that I can use the stored Auth token and secret of that user and show him his recent tweets in an iframe (like how the facebook social plugin provides their own interface and views for their recent activities, etc.)

I have also gone through the twitter gem, but I just get the data from that site; I need the same layout and view like twitter by using the iframe and twitter plugin.

Is there any way to do that with Rails app?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Twitter plugin, but change the script include. Instead of using the Twitter-provided `widget.js`, you'll use your own javascript file. Your own javascript file will be identical to `widget.js` except the REST call to `user_timeline` will include the oauth token and secret as parameters.

See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#Making_a_resource_request_on_a_user-s_behalf

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the data from twitter in text format, it is trivial to write your own view that uses this data from the Rails controller. you can render that view as a static webpage.

If you would like to do the same as an iframe, you may have to do the data fetching via javascript. you may use the Twitter javascript plugin and modify the call to the user's timeline to include his/her access token.